# How to set css3 animation inline or by javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, mvvm, css-animations, keyframe

I'd like to set css3 animation effect to multi element, but the animated position was related to the count of elements which is not certain. I had to set css style by js (maybe a mvvm framework).

sample code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes position {
    0% {left:0}
    100% {left: 5*elementCounts px;}
}
```

I found there's no way to set css property by data-*, neither to add inline css3 animation defining inline.
Anybody have idea to resolve this in css or mvvm way?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. If the number of possible ending positions is small and/or known in advance, you could write a number of variants of your keyframe definition with different names (`position10`, `position20`, etc).
2. If that is not an option, consider setting the element's position with jQuery so you can do all the calculations you need, and only relying on CSS for the animation duration. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yf9m5cy6/) showing how you can achieve that:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // calculate the intended location
    var div1Position = 100*1;
    var div2Position = 100*2;

    $('#div1').animate({ left: div1Position });
    $('#div2').animate({ left: div2Position });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1" class="box">Test #1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="box">Test #2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
}

.box {
    background-color: grey;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The number can be 12 at most, and have 1-4 directions leads to almost 30 kinds changes, it won't be a good decision to list all probable animation. jQuery is a choice , but i'd rather use original DOM options. I want some css solutions or mvvm friendly solutions witch I think is much more elegant.